# HERE Maps: Can't find domain whitelist feature

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

Any idea where I could find that feature from the docs?

1st image is my screenshot from my developer page

2nd is from the Here documentation
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to specify trusted domains is only available for application credentials of type **JAVASCRIPT**. This is not available for **REST**.

*Disclosure: I'm a product manager at HERE Technologies*